# access HttpPostedFile without saving, get error "Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..."

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can we access HttpPostedFile's uploaded file without saving the file. I am trying to read file's name and size but get error **"Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.**"

It works well on local host but this error accure on shared hosting server (GoDaddy). Please guide me a solution. I need to read some properties of files before saving it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file into a byte stream and then feed the byte stream into a FileInfo class.  But permissions may be preventing you from even reading the byte stream if Asp.Net does not have write access to the temp directory.  Could we see the code that throws the error?

**Edit**

I was wrong on the reading into a FileInfo class.  That will work if the file is physically pointed to on the server.  You should be able to get the filename of the file by call .FileName on the Request.Files[0] of the posted request.  If you wanted to read that into memory, it would look something like this:

```
 byte[] fileData = null; 
 using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream)) { fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength); }
```

Have you tried just looking at Request.Files[0].FileName to see if that returns the correct filename you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks Josh, you are right. I was passing file name into FileInfo class from HttppostedFile.

Can u plz also guide how I can read name of file usign byte strea and by feeding into FileInfo class ?